# How to include bundle correctly?

Tags: symfony

I have this error:

> Bundle "AcmeOggyBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php file?

Here is my `registerBundles` function in `AppKernel.php` file:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
        new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
        new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
        new Acme\OggyBundle\OggyBundle(),
    );

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}
```

I don't understand... I include bundle `new Acme\OggyBundle\OggyBundle()`, but get an error saying my bundle is not included! Why?

Log file:

```
[2013-06-13 10:46:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-06-13 10:46:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ChromePhpHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-06-13 10:46:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-06-13 10:46:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-06-13 10:46:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-06-13 10:46:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Fragment\FragmentHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-06-13 10:46:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-06-13 10:46:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-06-13 10:46:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-06-13 10:46:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-06-13 10:46:20] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
```

Comment: Could you provide us your directory structure of your bundle and the file of bundle itself? (ie.: file with same name of the bundle, contained into bundle folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your bundle's name is **Acme** OggyBundle ... then you need to register ...

```
// ...
new Acme\OggyBundle\AcmeOggyBundle(), 
// ...
```

... instead of

```
new Acme\OggyBundle\OggyBundle(),
```

The AcmeOggyBundle class has to be in the file ...

```
src/Acme/OggyBundle/AcmeOggyBundle.php
```

... with namespace **Acme\OggyBundle** and classname **AcmeOggyBundle**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\OggyBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeOggyBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

and if your bundle is still not loaded ... make sure the classes in the **src/** folder are being **autoloaded**.

Your composer.json has to contain

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    }
```

Afterwards run ...

```
composer update -o
```

... in order to regenerate the **vendor/autoload.php** which is generated by composer.

Comment: FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Acme\OggyBundle\AcmeOggyBundle' not found

Comment: instead src/Acme/OggyBundle/AcmeOggyBundle.php I have src/Acme/OggyBundle/OggyBundle.php and there instead class AcmeOggyBundle extends Bundle I have class OggyBundle extends Bundle

Comment: then change it accordingly. if you want to stick to the naming conventions. or change all references i.e. routing imports in routing.yml from `@AcmeOggyBundle` to `@OggyBundle` ... but it's a good practice to prefix bundle name's with the vendor name to avoid name collisions

Comment: I run composer update --o but get error **The "--o" option does not exist.**

Comment: sorry it's -o or --optimize-autoloader. updated my answer. If my answer helped you resolve the issue please upvote/accept to give some credit ;)

Comment: Yes I will resolve my question...but after **composer update -o** I steel have error PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Acme\OggyBundle\AcmeOggyBundle' not found in /var/www/symfony/test.dev/app/AppKernel.php on line 22

Comment: can you please provide a full exception trace on pastebin or similar ?

Comment: composer update -o command was finished in this error **An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command**

Comment: I was edit question...there i put a full trash which browser showing

Comment: Please double-check ... **1)** you have the file `src/Acme/OggyBundle/AcmeOggyBundle.php` **2)** this file contains `namespace Acme\OggyBundle;` and `class AcmeOggyBundle` **3)** your composer.json contains `psr-0": { "": "src/" }` **4)** AppKernel.php contains `new Acme\OggyBundle\AcmeOggyBundle(),` ... if still not working provide the full error log please!

Comment: what you posted in your answer is not the full exception trace and doesn't help like this.

Comment: Thank you for helping.
1) no - src/Acme/OggyBundle/OggyBundle.php
2) yes - namespace Acme\OggyBundle but class OggyBundle
3) yes
4) yes

Comment: I already told you to change the class- and filename. you have referenced @AcmeOggyBundle somewhere but you only have a OggyBundle ... just change it and the error is gone ... and you have a valid bundle-name with symfony naming-convention ! Just change it ... You should have said you are not going to change ... for whatever reason...

Comment: Logfile doesn't help - we need the exception trace ... Another thing ... Please look into your routing.yml and look for occurences `@AcmeOggyBundle` ... and replace with `@OggyBundle` ...

Comment: oh...sorry...so i just provide what you already told me...now browser show: **Cannot import resource "@OggyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml" from "/var/www/symfony/test.dev/app/config/routing.yml". Make sure the "OggyBundle" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class. **

Comment: okay we mixed it up ... if your bundle is AcmeOggyBundle then in your app/config/routing.yml there has to be @AcmeOggyBundle ... if your classname is just OggyBundle ... then your app/config/routing.yml has to contain `@OggyBundle` without Acme ... got it? But it should be AcmeOggyBundle to stick with the convention.

Comment: I put "Acme" to resource: "@OggyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml" so it should be like this resource: "@AcmeOggyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml" in my routing.yml file

Comment: I would accept your helping more than twice but I can only once :)